# Achieving Similar Scaling of Image Overlay on different image sizes

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, gdi+, system.drawing

I'm processing a large batch of images of different sizes.I'm overlaying an image on top of these images.I need to achieve uniform look across images of various sizes.See the images below

The orange rectangle is of the same size in both Image 1 and 2,but the the images does not look alike.How can i scale the orange rectangle so that it looks uniform across images of any size.

***Image1***
   [image]

***Image2***
[image]

I have tried the following

```
 scalewidth = (float)overlayimage.Width * ((float)currentimage.Width / (float)refsize.Width);

 scaleheight = (float)overlayimage.Height * ((float)currentimage.Height / (float)refsize.Height);
```

Comment: I assume you're rescaling the overlay using a reference size, to have constant proportions (if this is the part that `refsize` takes in the use case). You could use just one dimension and rescale the other after calculating the scale-factor. But, does the *canvas* really need to be resized when hosting a Bitmap? Wouldn't it be easier to maintain (and watch) if it was always the same size (zooming the content)?

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for your response.Yes,it's the reference image.To be clear -This is the use case I put a logo of a fixed size on an image of 800x800 pixel and the same on another one of 8000x8000 pixels.The first logo would appear larger while the second will appear too small.I need a uniform look for the logo.

Comment: Ah, I didn't get it right. This is not a *Control's surface* (used for presentation), it's an actual Bitmap where you need ot over-impress another translucent Bitmap. And you need to preserve the overlay proportions in relation to the Bitmap size. A relative position, too (distance from one of the dimensions)? Do the Bitmaps always have a Landscape layout or could they be In Portrait?

Comment: @Jimi It can be landscape or portrait.The spacing issue also needs to be taken care of. ie:Location of the logo

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by scaling foreground to background image width.

#### Get background width

```
b_h, b_w, b_ch = background.shape
o_h, o_w, o_ch = orange.shape
```

#### Scale orange rectangle

```
    imgScale = b_w/o_w
    new_o_h,new_o_w = int(o_h*imgScale), int(o_w*imgScale)
    new_orange = cv2.resize(orange,(new_o_w, new_o_h))
```

Now you can overlay.